# How can AvalonDock reference its own assembly?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/62498#1218343

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/AvalonDock;component/Resources/Common.xaml"/>
```

There must be something I don't understand about either the syntax of a ResourceDictionary's Source property, or how XAML is compiled.  I'd like to insert AvalonDock's source directly into a project, but it seems like some of its XAML files reference "the AvalonDock assembly".

How can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.source.aspx) property of the `ResourceDictionary` is actually a [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) which essentially represents a path to a resource. In this case, it just says to look in the `AvalonDock` assembly and find the `Common.xaml` file. See [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Programming_with_Pack_URIs) for more info.

If you want to include the AvalonDock source in your project, you should replace the `/AvalonDock;` part of the URI with the one of your project (if you put the Common.xaml file in the same directory as in the AvalonDock project).

Answer (score 0):

Since resolution of resources may happen from any other assembly, the source actually contains name of assembly where resource exist. Because when your app is running, how .net will find out from which assembly to load the URL?